# Reactjs + Material-ui , checkboxes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I just started learning React and for this app I am making, I use Material-UI. But I have issue with tap events. I added checkboxes but on click they don't get checked.

This is how my **index.js** file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';

import App from './components/App';



const theme = {
  textField: {

  }
}

render((
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Part of **package.json** file:

```
{
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.7.5",
"babel-eslint": "^6.0.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"eslint": "^2.7.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^7.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^0.6.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"file-loader": "^0.8.5",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^1.12.15",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"classnames": "^2.2.3",
"material-ui": "^0.15.0-beta.1",
"react": "^15.0.1",
"react-dom": "^15.0.1",
"react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0"
}
}
```

The **Navbar.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import styles from '../styles/Navbar.css';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className={cx('nav-wrapper', styles.navWrapper)}>
        <ul className={cx('left', 'navbarLeft', styles.navbarLeft, 'navbarCanvas')}>
          <li>
          <Checkbox
                label="Snap to grid"
                className={cx(styles.checkGrid)}
              />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

And the **App.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <h1>React!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to fix this for two days and no success. I have no idea what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide handlers so that the value of the checkbox is actually processed. For more information see the [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox).

For example, the following code should fix it (haven't tested it so there might be a small error):

```
export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {snapsToGrid: false};
  }
  snapsToGridChecked(event, checked) {
    this.setState({
      snapsToGrid: checked
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <nav>
        <div className={cx('nav-wrapper', styles.navWrapper)}>
          <ul className={cx('left', 'navbarLeft', styles.navbarLeft, 'navbarCanvas')}>
            <li>
            <Checkbox
                  label="Snap to grid"
                  className={cx(styles.checkGrid)}
                  checked={this.state.snapsToGrid}
                  onCheck={this.snapsToGridChecked.bind(this)}
                />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error: 
`TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined`
Tried to fix but no success. I will edit my question and post package.json file, maybe it will help.

Comment: @Plavookac In your constructor, try to pass the props to the `super` function. Like: `constructor(props) { super(props); .......`

Comment: @andré-junges Thanks, but that didn't worked, still the same error.

Comment: @Plavookac could you provide the current code you are using? based on janpieter suggestion..

Comment: @andré-junges Here https://gist.github.com/jelenajjo/29c6f58f63c1e68eb27316ee2bfecdf8

Comment: I've updated my answer to adopt the suggestions. If this doesn't solve it, what version of React and Babel are you running @Plavookac ?

Comment: @janpieter_z Huh.. now I have this error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` I updated my question so you can see package.json file and version of React and Babel.

Comment: I'm guessing the es6 function binding isn't enabled in your babel. Above example changed. @Plavookac

Comment: Now there is no error, but also on click, the checkbox don't get checked. How can I enable es6 binding function? Any informative link?

Comment: Can you console log the event and checked parameters and this, in the snapsToGrid method, to see what gets through, and if the click gets handled? es6 bindings are fun and helpful but not super useful for this, but check stuff here: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/